# Trouble with MySQL UPDATE syntax with the module mysqldb in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting to execute the following query via the mysqldb module in python:

for i in self.p.parameter_type:
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE parameters SET %s = %s WHERE parameter_set_name = %s""" % (i,
               float(getattr(self.p, i)), self.list_box_parameter.GetStringSelection()))

I keep getting the error: "Unknown column 'M1' in 'where clause'". I want to update columns i with the value getattr(self.p, i), but only in rows that have the column parameter_set_name equal to self.list_box_parameter.GetStringSelection(). The error suggests that my query is looking for columns by the name 'M1' in the WHERE clause. Why is the above query incorrect and how can I correct it?

Comment: what's stored in self.p.paremeter_type?

Comment: the names of the columns I want to update

Comment: No, M1 was the value obtained from self.list_box_parameter.GetStringSelection() in the above example. Sorry, I could probably have written the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see now, i think you need to enclose parameter_set_name = %s in quotes such as:

```
parameter_set_name = "%s"
```

otherwise it's trying to acces column M1

so:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE parameters SET %s = %s WHERE parameter_set_name = \"%s\" """ % (i, float(getattr(self.p, i)), self.list_box_parameter.GetStringSelection()))
```

Comment: That worked!! Thank you :) Why do I need the quotes for the third case of %s but not the 2nd case?

Comment: i'm guessing mysql sees a float number which cannot be column name so just works out that it's a value rather than a name

Answer (score 0):

It looks like query is formed with wrong syntax.
Could you display string parameter of cursor.execute?

Comment: For example, putting in actual strings instead of %s, the above query would like like:

UPDATE tablename SET columnname = "something" WHERE another_column_name = "something_else"

The error is suggesting that my where clause is searching for the column "something else" rather than the column another_column_name with the value "something_else"

Comment: I've tried the query with real strings in MySQL directly and that seemed to work. I believe the trouble is with the syntax around %s, or the way I am using cursor.execute ...

Comment: I mean that you should check EXACT (calculated) parameter of execute in debugger.